# Is there a command to delete/drop everything in a Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently learning my way around Postgres so I'm running lots of tests in an experimental database I set up. Is there an easy way to bring back the database into a "clean slate" state without recreating the database from scratch? I don't really want to have to enter the administrator password or reconfigure database permissions every time I want to get rid of all the mess I made.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If all the objects are owned by the same user you can use:

```
drop owned by db_user_name cascade;
```

This will drop all objects that the user `db_user_name` owns. This can be executed while being logged in as that user, so no special privileges are required.

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-drop-owned.html

Comment: So far, this is doing exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could, technically, drop the `public` schema and re-create *that*, if it's the only one you're using and you're confident that the rest was properly created or configured alongside (e.g. default collation). Be wary that many extensions install functions in `public` while you do.

Other than that, no… you'll be better off dropping the database and re-creating it if you want to start with a truly clean slate.